# Parsing a list with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm going to elaborate a file containing some text and email addresses in this way:

```
TEXT\n
Cc: mail1,\n
    mail2,\n
    mail3\n
EMPTY LINE\n
TEXT
```

I have to load into a bash variable the Cc list: FOO="mail1, mail2, mail3". How can I do with sed (or other command)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` normally evaluates only a single line at a time. You can get it to match multiple lines, but that's rather ugly. I'd suggest using `Perl` instead.

```
FOO=`perl -e 'local $/=undef; open FILE, "input.txt"; $text=<FILE>; close FILE; print "$1, $2, $3" if $text =~ /Cc: (.*?),\n (.*?),\n (.*?)\n/s;'`
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many addresses I have, I can use only the empty line as "end of mails", so I can't print $1 $2 $3. However thank you very much for your response.

Comment: You should have mentioned that before. Change `print "$1, $2, $3" if $text =~ /Cc: (.*?),\n (.*?),\n (.*?)\n/s;` into `if ($text =~ /Cc: (.*?(,\n .*?)*)\n/s) {$addr = $1; $addr =~ s/\n//g; print $addr;}` then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Procmail` installed and the input file is formatted as a single RFC822 email message like in the example,

```
FOO=$(formail -c -xCc: <file)
```